# SWING application hangs, much CPU consumed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, cpu-usage

I would like to ask your help to analyze the thread dump. I have a rich SWING application, one of the users claimed that it hangs on exit and running in background consuming much CPU. All what I have is the thread dump. "AWT-EventQueue-1" thread seems strange for me.

Do you have any idea what went wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```
2012-11-30 11:19:26
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode, sharing):

"Thread-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04aa8c00 nid=0x35ec runnable [0x07ccf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.shutdown(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04aa8000 nid=0x2b58 in Object.wait() [0x062ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x145b0020> (a javax.swing.TimerQueue)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x145b0020> (a javax.swing.TimerQueue)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"CacheCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04aa7000 nid=0x3184 in Object.wait() [0x05f0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1451f930> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1451f930> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04aa6c00 nid=0x2484 in Object.wait() [0x05e7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x145130c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x145130c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$LoadedResourceCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ConsoleWriterThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04aa6400 nid=0xb64 in Object.wait() [0x05def000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1439d3d0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.ConsoleTraceListener$ConsoleWriterThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1439d3d0> (a java.lang.Object)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x04aa6000 nid=0x3538 runnable [0x05d5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.addNativeDropTarget(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.addDropTarget(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x145b53c0> (a sun.awt.windows.WFramePeer)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14214c40> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.ConsoleWindow.showConsole(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.util.JavawsConsoleController.showConsoleIfEnable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x04aa5800 nid=0x365c runnable [0x05ccf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getWindowsParameters(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x143d9bb8> (a sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.updateProperties(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14216dc8> (a sun.awt.windows.WToolkit)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=6 tid=0x04aa5400 nid=0x3054 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java Web Start Main Thread" prio=6 tid=0x04aa2c00 nid=0x2d34 in Object.wait() [0x0523f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1423ec20> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1423ec20> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x391b9068> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.systemExit(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Javaws Secure Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04a9e800 nid=0x344c in Object.wait() [0x051af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1421b1d8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.sun.javaws.ui.JavawsSysRun$SecureThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1421b1d8> (a java.lang.Object)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04a9e000 nid=0x4dc runnable [0x0511f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x04a9dc00 nid=0x1fe4 in Object.wait() [0x0508f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x14210788> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14210788> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x04a9d400 nid=0x19ec in Object.wait() [0x04eaf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1421aab8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1421aab8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"traceMsgQueueThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x021c6400 nid=0x1968 in Object.wait() [0x047ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x141c0490> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x141c0490> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0217bc00 nid=0x3144 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02178400 nid=0x31b8 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02174000 nid=0x16ec waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0216f000 nid=0x2164 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x02167400 nid=0x9f8 in Object.wait() [0x0449f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x14191148> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14191148> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02166000 nid=0x2210 in Object.wait() [0x0440f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x14191048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x14191048> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02129400 nid=0x2ec0 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0218d800 nid=0x2848 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1323
```

Comment: Really hard to tell without context nor seeing any code. Somehown it seems that JWS controller attempts to display the console. Have you tried capturing thread dumps at several moments? Do the thread dumps change over time? Now, if you use `System.exit(0)` the system should exit no matter what happens.

Answer (score 1):

A [google search](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-analyze-java-thread-dumps/) on thread dump analysis to help you understand what you have in your hands.

Other than that, you may want to apply further analysis using, perhaps, [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), to also check GC frequency and heap usage.

Without more information about what your app does during the alleged slowdown period, that's the only tips we can give, I'm afraid.